# Set filename when downloading a file through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I've taken over the following snippet:

```
            $.ajax({
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/api/generalapi/generatecsv',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    window.open("data:text/csv;base64," + response, '', '');
                }
            });
```

I've tried adding

```
filename=orders.csv
```

to the window.open but the file still always comes down as "download". No extension or anything.

Is there any way of controlling the filename using the above code?

Answer (score 1):

try with something like this:

```
function saveContent(fileContents, fileName)
{
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName;
    link.href = 'data:,' + fileContents;
    link.click();
}

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/generalapi/generatecsv',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            saveContent("text/csv;base64," + response, 'orders.csv');
        }
    });
```

The key part is `link.download = fileName;`, which adds the HTML5 [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) attribute to the dynamically created link used for the download.

Comment: As this has to work in IE is my best option then to have the backend return the entire file thereby defining the filename?

Comment: indeed, IE doesn't support this, so yes, the option is to solve it from the backend